# Can I rough sand a deck before rain, and finish sand after rain dries?

Tags: deck, sanding, stain, rain

I am in the process of sanding and staining a new deck (built in June) but the weather is not being very cooperative. I know stain needs to sit 48 hrs before being rained on, and that wood needs to be dry and sanded before hand, meaning 24 to 48 hrs after a rain. So at a minimum I need 5 clear days, assuming 1 day in the middle for sanding and staining.

I am planning a 2 pass sanding job with a belt sander using 40 grit and a finish pass with an orbital using 80 grit. My question is, can I do my rough pass before a rain, and then do my finish pass 48 hours after the rain, and then stain? Or am I wasting my time sanding before the rain at all?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If the answer is good, please click the checkmark to accept it. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done deck railings and have split the sandings with rainfall in between with no problem. You just have to make sure the wood's dry before the second pass. Weather never cooperates when trying to sand/stain a deck. Get a waterproof tarp and keep the deck covered while you're working on it. It will save you a lot of time waiting for it to dry out after rain. Just make sure to allow for air flow. I always have a tarp handy when sealing decks.... you can't rely on the weatherman. Good luck.